# Is there a specific mustache syntax in Journey Builder Data Bindings for populations

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We have been using mustache in custom activities for a while succesfully, now we want to use data from a population so we do not duplicate the relationship in Attribute Groups.
But we cant find in the documentation any syntax related to populations and moustache to be used in data bindings for Journey Builder.
Have anybody used before mustache with populations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is the same as if you where using a DataExtension used in Data Designer.